# Strange bracket on the leagues page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2019-01-01?sort=reputationchange

> [image]

Comment: Someone) didn't pay enough attention when deploying a code change. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance you think they missed adding a ; and a - ? We all <3 SE developers ...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> a lone character)
>
> trailing after a mere link
>
> once was, is no more

Comment: The moral is that sometimes you think that you are missing a big part of yourself, and cannot be complete. When really, you are perfect just the way that you are.

Comment: So poetic, so special. You are so much more then a mere vessel.